# private key of keygen html5

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

For encryption there are several types of algorithms available over the internet (for example RSA in .net) in which we provide following

**string:** Taha Zubair

**Key:** 12456978

**Result:** AexcrX5TUOEpWKYSr7BPUlD8EoD17ijAGgyHQx4z==

on form submit we get a result like above.

So now talk about the feature of **Html5 keygen**

The keygen element represents a key pair generator control. When the control’s form is submitted, the private key is stored in the local keystore, and the public key is packaged and sent to the server.

here is code for html5 keygen

```
<form method="get">
    Username:
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <br/>
    Encryption: 
    <keygen name="encryption" />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    <br/>
</form>
```

on submit value = 'taha' from browser i get the below result

**string / value:** taha

**Key:** ?

**Result**: file:///D:/latest%20technologies/html5%20-%20working/html5-Forms.html?name=**taha**&encryption=MIICQDCCASgwggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQDHFLDvYzA5%0D%0ApeewYLYjedSAWMyFZwz4gZwhrQG2QRZI1jGtU9WqrWvpc37GpdWt5TKbUWKNXihH%0D%0AzvdRzC2knBQNh%2FX0Uq44mIYWFwAyaHUNyx6YdjkDR%2FVOs86FRNskdShPbIMQ7jnL%0D%0AsIKiJntztmVsquFgwhfDT6t3jLbFfPInukiS5Nuz%2FcISzLJH7YF8%2F6bPrwbCCOiC%0D%0AJM8scJMEMi3jaoVcQH6ffScrJUcnaFUm6x2AX1iqwtSEuBSRuvK3rrHgQXxeZ1ZT%0D%0AqjWBNEJNDkmWlHpRUTUR5GIPt2WUokjnokrXYmOyEAIyijkiNOrUA4WvYsBxpO26%0D%0A%2FA%2B6KIPE6IlhAgMBAAEWADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQQFAAOCAQEAT2XIdAedDknlNFe1%0D%0AiOLPVi9f68zPYYvxanTSNPSPCLIBq%2BICQ3r%2Fevl1%2FqG3iOEyhk07RuCMfGgrxML7%0D%0AIm87TJNZTHErYFmZ1wHcs3LPC2hQPJp2aiH%2B2pXmpN1LutKroN4aE%2BRJ%2Bb6%2BTu7B%0D%0AWguU0BGeIUSWOQl0eh9G8a2iAjzUFqLnBLKufH%2FKq8xg7C35NF2fAqdabnoN4XFd%0D%0A4wg8dI7lffsBwVLY6x6REt1R40lIUPfqeZwmJoh55BPeV2PZhMuFV8F49sr88aPg%0D%0Awp1WIQ56n9e3bKc3VFO48V3OZgCBi3Dk5NYWFxujFkOrK8hSNQAnTFVdVWoFZ5MI%0D%0AwXQcEQ%3D%3D

So i get the result but notice that the input taha is showing easily with encrypted text

Furthermore the most important question is where is the key of html5 keygen

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, your question isn't clear. Please read [faq] and [ask]

Answer (score 3):

The generated private key is stored in the browser's key storage (could also be added to the OS' key storage if the browser does not have its own). It is never sent to you as you are not supposed to access it.

What you get in the `encryption` parameter (you should use `method="post"` by the way) is the public key that corresponds to the private key. You can use it to create a certificate which you then most likely send back to the client so he can install it.